# Android - Intent ACTION_CALL without call log

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to invoke call action from my Activity, but after call action is finished my app stays on call log screen. To avoid this situation I decide to intent my activity from `PhoneStateListener`, and I do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlag(...);
startActivity(intent);
```

I tried many combination of flags but only result I get was that my activity wasn't on the front of activity stack or I get new instance of my activity. 
How can I get my activity (the same instance) on the front of activity stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read at the launchMode attribute for your Activity that can be set in the AndroidManifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

I believe what you're looking for is singleInstance.

Comment: Great I knew one of other options other than the standard default would be better for you. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Invoke/Start an application when a call is ended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034183/how-to-invoke-start-an-application-when-a-call-is-ended)

Please see this you can find the answer!
in there change the package as in the answer!